# Central database for an android app

Tags: android, database, remote-access

I'm a beginner on developing Android applications and I want to create an app (just for practising) to connect to a remote database and then add or modify rows.

An example of what I want could be an application with two buttons: the first button sends your location to the database and with the second you can see the locations of other users. In this case the database could have one table with two columns (username and location).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at using [PHP with MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/).

Comment: Thanks. The example is close to what I want, but I don't want use a local server. Is possible to do the same in a remote server accessible by anyone? What tool should I use?

Comment: That same technique will work with a remote server.  The example that is given is provided for ease of understanding.

Comment: Yes! Now it works. It was a problem with the configuration of remote server. I'll take this example to build my app. Thank you for your reply it was very useful to me.